# Advertising in iOS app

Tags: ios, ads

I would like to know if it's possible to have a UIImageView on the main page of my app, where the ImageView would show a logo of some company, that I will advertise in my app, and have a contract "behind" with that company.

I searched some forums and Advertising Guidelines, but it's all about iAd. So I was wondering if Apple would approve this app?

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering Apple allows other advertising frameworks like Admob, it doesn't seem your app will be rejected because of this.

The only review guidelines regarding advertisements you should keep in mind are:

> Apps that artificially increase the number of impressions or
>   click-throughs of ads will be rejected
>
> Apps that contain empty iAd banners will be rejected
>
> Apps that are designed predominantly for the display of ads will be
>   rejected

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there will be a problem , after all apps promote other apps all the time, why not companies.

Your advertising would be like just any ad network, but instead of having a server you have it locally,that's it.